# Object Box error on app start - No implementation found for void io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeDelete(long)

Tags: android, objectbox

Pretty much as the title says.

When I start my Android app I get the following error

```
No implementation found for void io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeDelete(long)
```

I will add my full build.gradle and app code in a bit, as I'm in a rush, but thought I should post, just in case there is a known and obvious solution.

I've tried both 1.1.0 and 1.2.0

UPDATE:

Some further information. I'm trying to use ObjectBox in my LibGDX project. LibGDX is a cross platform game lib, that you write the code in Java, and it spits out Android, iOS and Desktop versions.

Rather than using the Android implementation of ObjectBox, I decided to try and use the Java version so that in theory it can be used on all three platforms. I'm not sure, but maybe this is the issue. Using the Java version but on an Android platform.

UPDATE 2: (Stacktrace)

```
11-10 09:48:05.159 16269-16278/com.myapp E/System: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeDelete(long) (tried Java_io_objectbox_BoxStore_nativeDelete and Java_io_objectbox_BoxStore_nativeDelete__J)
                                                                              at io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeDelete(Native Method)
                                                                              at io.objectbox.BoxStore.close(BoxStore.java:355)
                                                                              at io.objectbox.BoxStore.finalize(BoxStore.java:245)
                                                                              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
                                                                              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
11-10 09:48:05.261 16269-16269/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.myapp, PID: 16269
                                                                                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libobjectbox.so"
                                                                                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
                                                                                      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
                                                                                      at io.objectbox.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.<clinit>(NativeLibraryLoader.java:44)
                                                                                      at io.objectbox.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.ensureLoaded(NativeLibraryLoader.java:82)
                                                                                      at io.objectbox.BoxStore.<init>(BoxStore.java:170)
                                                                                      at io.objectbox.BoxStoreBuilder.build(BoxStoreBuilder.java:243)
                                                                                      at com.myapp.db.DB.createMyObjectBox(DB.java:28)
                                                                                      at com.myapp.db.DB.updateAchievements(DB.java:35)
                                                                                      at com.myapp.screens.MainMenuScreen.achievementsFinishedLoading(MainMenuScreen.java:1241)
                                                                                      at com.myapp.android.AndroidPlayServices$GetAchievementsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(AndroidPlayServices.java:418)
                                                                                      at com.myapp.android.AndroidPlayServices$GetAchievementsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(AndroidPlayServices.java:364)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
1
```

build.gradle (a lot of it can potentially be ignored, but it's the 'core' project that I am using ObjectBox in, not the Android one. Also, as I know my machine is Linux 64bit I decided to comment out all the detection stuff and the windows stuff and just use the linux extension/lib)

```
buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = '1.1.0'
//    ext {
//        osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
//        isLinux = osName.contains("linux")
//        isWindows = osName.contains("windows")
//        is64 = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") == "64"
//        isLinux64 = isLinux && is64
//        isWindows64 = isWindows && is64
//    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/" }
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        google()
    }
//        https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml look here for up to date fabric version

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.12"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Masters Gallery by Reiner Knizia"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
        aiVersion = '1.6.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
        google()
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
//    apply plugin: 'io.objectbox' // after applying Android plugin

    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    }
    // .aar repositories
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    }

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
        compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt-idea'
    apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-java:$objectboxVersion"

        // everything compiles without this, but it might still be needed
//        if (isLinux64) {
//            compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-linux:$objectboxVersion"
//        } else if (isWindows64) {
//            compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-windows:$objectboxVersion"
//        } else println("Native dependency could not be set up for unsupported OS: " + osName)

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.aar')
    }
}
```

DB Class using ObjectBox

```
private void createMyObjectBox() throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("objectstorefile", "");
    tempFile.delete();
    boxStoreDir = tempFile;
    Gdx.app.error("DB","tempfile="+tempFile);
    Gdx.app.error("DB","boxstoredir="+boxStoreDir);
    store = MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build();
}
```

Comment: Please post the full call stack - I wonder what makes that call to nativeDelete.

Comment: Hi @Markus, I'll add this at lunchtime. Thanks for responding so quickly

Comment: @MarkusJunginger hopefully that is enough to at least have a look at. (Sorry for formatting issues on stacktrace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you only define ObjectBox dependencies in a Java project. What seems to be missing is the Android specific artifact:

```
compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"
```

This includes the shared libraries (native .so files).

Other notes:

- Ensure that you have consistent ABI support through all your libraries. It looks like your LibGDX comes with armeabi, which is very old and is thus not included in ObjectBox. ObjectBox Android comes with armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, and x86 support. I'd suggest removing all others from your LibGDX setup. Otherwise the app might crash on some devices because it cannot mix 32 and 64 bit libraries.
- You could give ObjectBox for desktop a try by adding compile `"io.objectbox:objectbox-linux:$objectboxVersion"` to the desktop project for your Linux machine
- The ObjectBox version you are using is outdated. Please check the [changelog](http://objectbox.io/changelog/) for the most recent version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a try tonight.

As I said in one of my updates, my library is a cross platform one, which is written in Java, and then can create Android, iOS and desktop versions. I was hoping to use one DB in the Java "core" project, hence why I didn't include the Android version in gradle. But if it appears that I can't use this, and I have to use the Android one on Android, and then potentially a future iOS version when it's released, then so be it. Just a shame that's all

Comment: Also, I know it's an old version. I tried both 1.2.0 and 1.1.0, but when I copy pasted this, I hadn't changed it back to 1.2.0 :D
As for the abi stuff, that's good to know. I know that armeabi is old, and had it in there for the very few old phones out there. But if ObjectBox won't work with it, I might as well remove it.

Comment: As for the desktop suggestion, that's what I'm trying in my java "core" project, which is pure Java and not Android. The desktop project is an actual desktop app, which is not what I'm releasing, so to put it in there won't get used.

Comment: Usually it's faster to develop on the desktop - libGDX and ObjectBox support that.

Comment: True (know LibGDX do you, sorry for patronisingly explaining it then!) But if I'm not going to release on desktop, only on Android, then I will need to add the Android version, to the Android project it would seem, and have nothing in the core project.

Comment: This comments thread might be getting a little spammy/chatty...
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/158710/objectbox?tab=general

Comment: So it worked if I stuck the compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion" in the core project. A bit odd that, as if I ever create an iOS project, then maybe I'll have to add the iOS lib as well, and could get a clash. Either way, I think it's working at the moment

Comment: Did you try to put objectbox-android just in the Android project? Would make more sense...

Comment: I did, and it appears to work :D I didn't use the apply plugin: 'io.objectbox' though